# How can I debug a youtube flash embed's behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, youtube, firebug

A youtube embed I am using seems to freeze (pause and becomes unresponsive) when I mouse over it. It only happens on chrome, not firefox, and I think it is because of those thumnail previews when you go to fastforward but have no way of checking.

Does anyone know how I can track or diagnose what could be changing the youtube players state?
I have a function set up when it becomes paused, stopped, buffering, and youtube's errors (from their API) but none of these are being triggered. Is there something else you'd suggest using? perhaps in firebug or the like?

Answer (score 2):

Use mm.cfg with [Vizzy](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and a [debug player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#main-pars_text_5) to see what events are happening on the Flash side. A [heap snapshot](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling) may help isolate the issue as well.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I'll hopefully be able to try those out soon. I appreciate it!